# String Literal As Template Argument

Tags: c++, templates

These preprocessor and template limitations of c++ are killing me.
The goal is to convert string literals into integers.

```
template<const char* str>
inline int LiteralToInt(){
    return __COUNTER__;
}

using std::cout;

int main(){
    cout << LiteralToInt<"Hello">();
    cout << LiteralToInt<"No">();
    cout << LiteralToInt<"Hello">();
    return 0;
}
```

The output would be 010 if templates accepted string literals. Is there another way to get this output and convert string literals to integers at compile time?

Comment: If you use the address of the literal, it could just as well produce `012`. Merging identical string literals is not required by the language. And if `__COUNTER__` is the VC++ macro, it would likely be `111` becuse the macro is expanded only once.

Comment: even if most compilers do merge identical literals, they don't do it for different translation units. Too much hassle and too little gain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I know of no way to do exactly what you want.

Are there any restrictions you can put on the strings? Like number of characters? If you can limit it to 1-8 characters, you can do something like this:

```
template <char Ch1, char Ch2 = '\0', char Ch3 = '\0', char Ch4 = '\0', char Ch5 = '\0', char Ch6 = '\0', char Ch7 = '\0', char Ch8 = '\0'>
struct string_hash {
    static const uint64_t value = 
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(Ch1) << 56) | 
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(Ch2) << 48) | 
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(Ch3) << 40) | 
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(Ch4) << 32) | 
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(Ch5) << 24) | 
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(Ch6) << 16) | 
        (static_cast<uint64_t>(Ch7) << 8)  | 
        (Ch8);
};
```

which basically, at compile time stuff up to `8` characters into a `uint64_t`. Usage would look like this:

```
const uint64_t x = string_hash<'T', 'e', 's', 't'>::value
```

This will create a compile time numeric value (can be used in a `switch` and all that goodness) unique to each string 1-8 chars long. Unfortunately, the only big downside is that you can't write it as a string literal, you need to write it as a list of `char`s

Comment: The impetus behind this is to make my life easier. This is a valid way of doing it albeit unproductive. If it was really important i could do it like this.

Comment: Accepted as a work around until constexpr gets widespread implementation.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, C++ 11's `constexpr` will do this for you:

```
 constexpr int LiteralToInt(const char * str) {
      return __COUNTER__; // or whatever.
 }
```

Comment: I looked into that but constexpr is not implemented in the majority of compilers.

Comment: That wont give a different value to each string though.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work

```
extern const char HELLO[] = "Hello";
```

and then

```
cout << LiteralToInt<HELLO>();
```

but not the literal itself. This is probably not what you want.

String literals themselves, as you already discovered, cannot be used as template arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of thinking about [Richard J Ross III's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788834/string-literal-as-template-argument/11789684#11789684) using constexpr gave me the right key to search with... What you're essentially doing is hashing a string at compile time. You can do this in C++11 (but not earlier versions) as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111667/compile-time-string-hashing).

The basic idea is to use something like this:

```
unsigned int constexpr const_hash(char const *input) { 
    // really simple hash function...
    return static_cast<unsigned int>(*input) 
         && static_cast<unsigned int>(*input) + hash(input+1); 
}
```

But you probably want to use a hash function with more robust properties than this...

However if you're not using C++11 then my earlier statement holds:

No - there is no way to convert string literals to integers at compile time, in such a way that all of the same strings map to same values, (and different strings map to different values) across all compilation units, short of processing the code in some way.