# Is a string literal not acceptable as a template argument in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Page 724 , Chapter 25, The C++ Programming Language

A pointer used as a template argument must be of the form `&of`, where of is the name of an object or a function, or of the form `f`, where `f` is the name of a function. A pointer to member must be of the form `&X::of`, where of is the name of a member. In particular, a string literal is not acceptable as a template argument:

```
template<typename T, char∗ label>
class X {
    // ...
};
X<int,"BMW323Ci"> x1; // **error : string literal as template argument**
char lx2[] = "BMW323Ci";
X<int,lx2> x2; // OK: lx2 has exter nal linkage
```

Page 725 , Chapter 25, The C++ Programming Language

This becomes particularly useful when combined with a default template argument (§25.2.5); for
example:

```
template<typename T, T default_value = T{}>
class Vec {
    // ...
};
Vec<int,42> c1;
Vec<int> c11; // default_value is int{}, that is, 0
Vec<string,"fortytwo"> c2;  // **I'm confused!**
Vec<string> c22; // default_value is string{}; that is, ""
```

Comment: Didn't you just answer your question yourself?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788834/string-literal-as-template-argument

Comment: No. why {{ X<int,"BMW323Ci"> x1  }} is wrong, but {{Vec<string,"fortytwo"> c2;}} is OK ?

Comment: Did you try to declare `template<typename T, const char∗ label> class X`?

Comment: Have you tried to compile this? If so, which compiler have you used? Because [it doesn't work on Ideone](http://ideone.com/OOYbmx).

Comment: The issue with string literals is that when you use `"abcd"` in two or more translation units, there may be one copy of `"abcd"` in the executable file or there may be more than one. If using a string literal as a template argument was legal, `my_template<"abcd">"` might name the same type everywhere, or it might name to different types in two different translation units. This would be a portability nightmare.

Comment: Vec<string,"fortytwo"> c2;   This is an error in this book.

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T, T default_value = T{}>
class Vec {
    // ...
};
Vec<string,"fortytwo"> c2;
Vec<string> c22;
```

Neither declaration involving `string` is legal at all.

14.1/4:

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall have one of the following (optionally *cv-qualified*) types:
>
> - integral or enumeration type,
> - pointer to object or pointer to function,
> - lvalue reference to object or lvalue reference to function,
> - pointer to member,
> - `std::nullptr_t`.

14.1/7:

> A non-type *template-parameter* shall not be declared to have floating point, **class**, or void type.

Answer (score 0):

A string literal is not acceptable as a template argument. With the first template, you have to declare a char array to be used as template argument.

With the second template, the "fortytwo" isn't a string literal. Instead, it is a std::string.

Comment: The template argument `"fortytwo"` is still a string literal.  There's a difference in the type of the template parameter it initializes, though....

Comment: Yes. Its type is inferred from the first one (template T).

Comment: An argument for a template value parameter can be (§iso.14.3.2):
• An integral constant expression (§10.4)
• A pointer or a reference to an object or a function with external linkage (§15.2)
• A nonoverloaded pointer to member (§20.6)
• A null pointer (§7.2.2)