# Non type function template parameter with pointer data type

Tags: c++

I am learning meta programming in c++ using templates concept.

I have the below question.

**What i understood?**

1) INTEGER can be used as a non type template parameter.

```
template <typename T, int VALUE>
T addBoth(T const & a)
{
   return VALUE + a;
}
```

I understood the above concept.

**what i do not understand?**

2)

```
template <typename T, char *name>
class Test .....


Test<10, "StackOverflow"> sTest;

Reason: String literals are objects with internal linkage.
```

I dont understand above 2nd Point.

Could someone kindly elaborate on it?

Answer (score 2):

So this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547852/string-literals-not-allowed-as-non-type-template-parameters) should have all the information you need, but here's a summary.

Quote used in OP text:

> Because string literals are objects with internal linkage (two string
>   literals with the same value but in different modules are different
>   objects), you can't use them as template arguments either.

So [Tony](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5547975/1508519) explains why you can't do this.

Code example:

```
#include <iostream>

template <const char* P> void f() { std::cout << P << '\n'; }

int main() {
    f<"hello there">();
}
```

Reasoning:

> ...because "hello there" isn't 100% guaranteed to resolve to a single
>   integral value that can be used to instantiate the template once
>   (though most good linkers will attempt to fold all usages across
>   linked objects and produce a new object with a single copy of the
>   string).

[Mikael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5548037/1508519) elaborates:

> Obviously, string literals like "foobar" are not like other literal
>   built-in types (like int or float). They need to have an address
>   (const char*). The address is really the constant value that the
>   compiler substitutes in place of where the literal appears. That
>   address points to somewhere, fixed at compile-time, in the program's
>   memory.
>
> It has to be of internal linkage because of that. Internal linkage
>   just means that cannot be linked across translation units (compiled
>   cpp files). The compiler could try to do this, but is not required to.
>   In other words, internal linkage means that if you took the address of
>   two identical literal strings (i.e. the value of the const char* they
>   translate to) in different cpp files, they wouldn't be the same, in
>   general.
>
> You can't use them as template parameters because they would require a
>   strcmp() to check that they are the same. If you used the ==, you
>   would just be comparing the addresses, which wouldn't be the same when
>   template are instantiated with the same literal string in different
>   translation units.
>
> Other simpler built-in types, as literals, are also internal linkage
>   (they don't have an identifier and can't be linked together from
>   different translation units). However, their comparison is trivial, as
>   it is by value. So they can be used for templates.