# How to set string as value template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates

```
template<typename T,T default_value=T{}>
class Vec{};

Vec<string,"abc"> vs;
```

I get an error:
'class std::basic_string' is not a valid type for a template non-type parameter

Comment: They are called "non-type template parameters", which should help you find further info about them more easily. (BTW, string literals aren't allowed either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547852/string-literals-not-allowed-as-non-type-template-parameters)

Comment: The answer is confusing. I understand a string literal is not acceptable as a template argument. However, the code is from "the c++ programming language" -- Bjarne Stroustrup, Ch25.2.2 values as arguments. Check it out.