# How to automate class declarations?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have some exceptions derived from `std::exception` or `std::runtime_error`. The only method is constructor `explicit MyExceptionX(const char *text = "") : std::exception(text) {}`. Are there ways to make this code simpler without use of macro?

```
class MyException1: public std::exception
{
public:
    explicit MyException1(const char *text = "") : std::exception(text) {}
};

class MyException2: public std::exception
{
public:
    explicit MyException2(const char *text = "") : std::exception(text) {}
};

class MyException3: public std::exception
{
public:
    explicit MyException3(const char *text = "") : std::exception(text) {}
};

//...
```

Comment: Is your code supposed to compile?

Comment: I think this is a valid case to use macro.

Comment: What I meant was, please post some code that at least compiles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no need to use `class` when everything is public.  You can use `struct` instead.  Also, you can inherit constructors:

```
struct MyException1: std::exception
{
    using std::exception::exception;
};

struct MyException2: std::exception
{
    using std::exception::exception;
};

struct MyException3: std::exception
{
    using std::exception::exception;
};
```

Also, if you really just need different types, you can do this:

```
template <int>
struct MyException : std::exception
{
    using std::exception::exception;
};


using MyException1 = MyException<1>;
using MyException2 = MyException<2>;
using MyException3 = MyException<3>;
```

You can use an `enum` instead of an `int` if you want more descriptive names.

Comment: I like your suggestion but I usually use it with an `enum` like so: `enum class my_problems { no_money, no_love, no_sleep }; template <my_problems> struct my_exception : std::exception {};` Then you can say things like `my_exception<my_problems::no_sleep>` which I find very expressive. You might not need the `using` alias at all any more.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Agreed. I started to do it that way, but it ended up looking silly for this example: `enum class ExceptionId {one,two,three}`.

Comment: I see what you mean. That's the problem with contrived examples.

Comment: @5gon12eder: I added a note about that.

Comment: @vaughn-cato `struct MyException1 : public std::runtime_error
{
    using std::runtime_error::runtime_error;
};`
 `throw MyException1("error");`
 error C2440: '<function-style-cast>' : cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'MyException1'

Comment: @Ufx: May be an issue with the compiler.  I'm not seeing that: https://ideone.com/HNwHqO

Comment: @vaughn-cato MSVC120. cannot convert from 'const char [6]' to 'MyException1'. No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload resolution was ambiguous

Comment: @Ufx: Looks like MSVC 12 didn't support inheriting constructors.

Comment: @vaughn-cato are inheriting constructors in C++ standard?

Comment: @Ufx Are you deriving from `std::exception` directly as shown in your question? It doesn't have a constructor that takes a message so you cannot inherit it. Derive from `std::runtime_error` (or some related `class`) instead. I guess it's this that was meant by “Is your code supposed to compile?”

Comment: Compiles in MSVC140. Doesn't in MSVC120 .

Answer (score 0):

You can be `using` the superclass' constructor. The following simplified code example does what you are looking for:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
public:
  A(char* cText) {
    std::cout << cText << std::endl;
  }

  ~A() {
  }
};

class B : public A {
public:
  using A::A;

  ~B() {
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  B("Test");

  return 0;
}
```

Additionally, the `using` feature for inheriting constructors is only available when compiling with `-std=c++11` or `-std=gnu++11`.

Comment: A better solution would be to not use `new` and `delete` at all.

Comment: @BryanChen no, you don't. It works like a charm without making `~A()` virtual. Making it virtual actually *chages* what the effect of the polymorphism is w.r.t. what gets executed when deconstructing the class. Additionally, polymorphism of the destructor is not subject to OP's question.

Comment: @juanchopanza Acknowledged, I'll change that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The following compiles fine in my VisualStudio 2012:

```
template <const char *&text>
class MyException: public std::exception
{
public:
    virtual const char* what() const { return(text); }
};

const char *Ex1 = "Message1";
const char *Ex2 = "Message2";
const char *Ex3 = "Message3";

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    throw MyException<Ex1>();
    throw MyException<Ex2>();
    throw MyException<Ex3>();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately C++ does not allow using string literals in the throw statement itself. Details can be found here:  [String literals not allowed as non type template parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547852/string-literals-not-allowed-as-non-type-template-parameters).