# How to convert a string to chars during compiling (metaprogramming)

Tags: c++, metaprogramming

Suppose I want to perform a number of actions on the "before" string he enters Binary.

My main problem is literal string, I try to perform actions and save the resulting string and then perform other actions on the resulting string.

I've created this mini-code:

```
template <char one_char>
struct deal_with_one_char
{
    enum { my_val = one_char ^ 0x55};
};


template <char ... Chars>
struct deal_with_milty_char
{
    static const char My_string[sizeof...(Chars)+1];
};

template <char ... Chars>
char const deal_with_milty_char< Chars ...>::My_string[sizeof...(Chars)+1] = { deal_with_one_char<Chars>::my_val ...};

int main()
{
    cout << deal_with_milty_char<'H', 'B', 'R'>::My_string << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And it works, of course, because it inhabits a global array while compiling and everything is good. 
The question is how do I bridge the existing gap and insert a regular string and convert it into a series of characters so that it can use the functions.

An example illustrating what I'm trying to do:

```
#define CompleteStr(str) (do something to converrt str to deal_with_milty_char<'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'w', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd'>::My_string)

int main()
{
    cout << CompleteStr("hello world")::My_string << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Of course everything must be done during compiling.

Conceptually, I try to make the templet relate to my string as a sequence of bytes with separation rather than as one string. The problem is that it is not so clear to me how to do it ...

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44684103/is-there-a-reason-string-literals-cant-have-external-linkage

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conveniently Declaring Compile-Time Strings in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c)