# Passing a string literal to a template char array parameter

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, string-literals, compile-time

The [CTRE library](https://github.com/hanickadot/compile-time-regular-expressions) is able to parse and validate regular expressions at compile time using syntax like `ctre::match<"REGEX">(text_to_search)`. I know this syntax is only supported in C++20, which is fine, but I am unable use string literals this way no matter what I try. Here's a very simple example:

```cpp
// The compiler refuses to pass string literals to STR in this compile time version.
template <char const STR[2]> constexpr int to_int_compile_time()
{
    return STR[0] - '0';
}

// It has no problems passing the string literal to str in this version.
int to_int_runtime(char const str[2])
{
    return str[0] - '0';
}
```

Calling `to_int_runtime("0")` works fine, but `to_int_compile_time<"0">()` complains that string literals can't be used for this template parameter. How should `to_int_compile_time` be written so that the string literal can be passed into the char array template paramter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Being able to do this hinges on a little-known feature of C++20: a non-type template parameter can have a class template type, **without template arguments specified**. CTAD will determine those arguments.

So you create a class templated by `size_t N`, that has `char[N]` as a member, is constructible from one, and `N` is deducible by CTAD.

Example:

```
// This does nothing, but causes an error when called from a `consteval` function.
inline void expectedNullTerminatedArray() {}

template <std::size_t N>
struct ConstString
{
    char str[N]{};

    static constexpr std::size_t size = N - 1;

    [[nodiscard]] constexpr std::string_view view() const
    {
        return {str, str + size};
    }

    consteval ConstString() {}
    consteval ConstString(const char (&new_str)[N])
    {
        if (new_str[N-1] != '\0')
            expectedNullTerminatedArray();
        std::copy_n(new_str, size, str);
    }
};
```

Then you do `template <ConstString S> struct A {...};`, and use either `S.str` or `S.view()` to examine the string.

And here are some extra convenience operators for this class:

```
template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstString<A + B - 1> operator+(const ConstString<A> &a, const ConstString<B> &b)
{
    ConstString<A + B - 1> ret;
    std::copy_n(a.str, a.size, ret.str);
    std::copy_n(b.str, b.size, ret.str + a.size);
    return ret;
}

template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstString<A + B - 1> operator+(const ConstString<A> &a, const char (&b)[B])
{
    return a + ConstString<B>(b);
}

template <std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstString<A + B - 1> operator+(const char (&a)[A], const ConstString<B> &b)
{
    return ConstString<A>(a) + b;
}
```

You can also have template UDLs with this class:

```
template <ConstString S>
struct ConstStringParam {};

template <ConstString S>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr ConstStringParam<S> operator""_c()
{
    return {};
}

// -----

template <ConstString S> void foo(ConstStringParam<S>) {}

foo("Sup!"_c);
```

Comment: I've tried doing similar things, but I can't find a way to access the characters in the string in compile time expressions. For example, I replaced `ASSERT(new_str[N-1] == '\0');` with `static_assert`, since that's where I'm trying to go with this, and the compiler does not consider `new_str[N-1]` a valid constexpr expression.

Comment: @BobBuilder You don't need a static one. The standard `assert()` will work, because on the happy path it's constexpr. I've edited the answer to not confuse anyone.

Comment: Are you referring to `assert()` from `assert.h`? I tried using that one, and it compiles but does not check anything at compile time. As a simple test, I put in `assert(new_str[0] == something_that_gives_a_false_result)`, and it still compiles without errors.

Comment: @BobBuilder Yes, but I just figured out a better test, see the edit.

Comment: Thank you, that last edit achieves compile time string validation. It feels a bit like a hack, but it's the only thing I've seen that actually solves the problem. :)

Comment: @BobBuilder: Everyone wants to just have the string literal **be** the template argument, but string literals are very old and very special and making them more regular is much harder than it sounds.