How to make unique data type for string literal?
This is my log entity structure. It represents a request to log something.
    union log_entity_t
    {
#pragma pack(1)
        struct
        {
            uint64_t timestamp; 
            void (*printer)(const char *, std::ostream &); // will print data to stream
            Severity severity; // int denoting log level
            uint32_t ld; // log descriptor. mapped to some file where log is printed.
            uint8_t buffer[1]; // 256-24 = 232 bytes data will be stored here 
        } data;
#pragma pack(1)

        uint8_t __raw[256];
    };

I fill this with the following functions:
template <Severity severity, typename... Args>
inline void fill_log_entity(log_entity_t &entity, const Args &...args)
{
    entity.data.timestamp = static_cast<uint64_t>(std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count());
    entity.data.severity = severity;
    if constexpr (is_empty<Args...>)
    {
         entity.data.printer = &(dummy_printer);
    }
    else
    {
         log_entity_memcpy(reinterpret_cast<char *>(entity.data.buffer), args...);
         entity.data.printer = &(printer<Args...>);
    }
}

template <size_t filled>
inline void log_entity_memcpy(const char *data)
{
    static_assert(filled + offsetof(decltype(log_entity_t::data), buffer) <= sizeof(log_entity_t), "log structure is too large");
}
        
template <size_t offset = 0, typename A, typename... Args>
inline void log_entity_memcpy(char *data, const A &a, const Args &...args)
{
    static_assert(__check_logable_entity<A>::is_logable);
    if constexpr (__check_logable_entity<A>::raw_string)
    {
        strncpy(data + offset, a, max_string_size);
        log_entity_memcpy<offset + max_string_size, Args...>(data, args...);
    }
    else if constexpr (__check_logable_entity<A>::is_string)
    {
        strncpy(data + offset, a.c_str(), max_string_size);
        log_entity_memcpy<offset + max_string_size, Args...>(data, args...);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(data + offset, &a, sizeof(A));
        log_entity_memcpy<offset + sizeof(A), Args...>(data, args...);
    }
}

template <typename A, typename... Args>
inline void printer(const char *data, std::ostream &out)
{
    static_assert(__check_logable_entity<A>::is_logable, "not logable");
    if constexpr (__check_logable_entity<A>::is_string)
    {
        char buffer[max_string_size + 1];
        buffer[max_string_size] = '\0';
        strncpy(buffer, data, max_string_size);
        out << buffer;
        data += max_string_size;
    }
    else if constexpr (__check_logable_entity<A>::is_timestamp)
    {
        out << static_cast<uint64_t>((*reinterpret_cast<const A *>(data)).time_since_epoch().count());
        data += sizeof(A);
    }
    else if constexpr (__check_logable_entity<A>::logable_struct)
    {
        A::logwrite(data, out);
        data += sizeof(A);
    }
    else if constexpr (__check_logable_entity<A>::is_logable)
    {

        out << *reinterpret_cast<const A *>(data);
        data += sizeof(A);
    }
    if constexpr (!is_empty<Args...>)
    {
        printer<Args...>(data, out);
    }
}


The program is working. There is a loger running on another thread which reads and prints a log entity using
void Logger::Logger::print_log_entity(const log_entity_t &entity, std::ostream &out)
{
    out << entity.data.timestamp << " :: ";
    out << entity.data.severity << " :: ";
    entity.data.printer(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(entity.data.buffer), out);
    out << std::endl;
}

The issue I have is with string literals.
If a char* or string is passed, I reserve 20 bytes and copy the string. To print larger strings, I have a templated structure
template <size_t N>
struct log_string
{
    constexpr log_string(const char (&str)[N]);
    char value[N];
    inline static void logwrite(const char *loc, std::ostream &out);
};

But the thing is that string literals are known at compile time. It is a waste to copy literals. What I want is to have unique data types for unique string literals. That way, the requirement to print the string can be sent via the template function and no data needs to be copied. However, string literal cannot be templated directly. The solution I found was:
constexpr char* msg = "message to print";
dummy_type<msg>

However, I would like to have a solution where the user of the function doesn't need to declare and use these constexpr variables.

Why not just change char value[N] to const char* value? If the log message is always a string literal then you can just store the pointer and no copying is required

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68024633/2752075

It looks like the first three code blocks are mere context. They could probably be reduced to a few sentences (no code) to make it easier to focus on your real question.

Don't do it. A string literal is just a const char*or const char[], which can also be returned from other functions, so it's difficult to auto-detect a literal. And while you could use different entry points aka log(whatever) and log_literal("foo"), that's just annoying for users. At the end of the day, how many log messages per second do you intend to print? You're optimizing something that doesn't need optimization...

The requirement is that when the log function is called, the control returns in near about 100 ns. The threads calling the log function need to be low latency as it will be processing real time data.
